# java - problema con enum y java.lang.string

Tags: java, enum

Estoy programando un método para que, dado un color, me devuelva una posición de un futbolista definido con `enum`

```
enum Position{
    GOALKEEPER, DEFENDER, MIDFIELDER, FORWARD;
}

public String getPositionByColor (String color) {
        switch (color){
            case "BLACK":
                return Position.GOALKEEPER;
            case "RED":
                return Position.DEFENDER;
            case "GREEN":
                return Position.MIDFIELDER;
            case "BLUE":
                return Position.FORWARD;
        }
}
```

El error que me muestra es *`required: 'java.lang.String'`*

He probado a hacer `return Position.toString(Position.GOALKEEPER);` pero obtengo otro error que no sé corregir *`Non-static method 'toString()' cannot be referenced from a static context`* Entiendo que `toString()` no es la forma adecuada.

Los test que debo pasar, por si sirven de algo, son los siguientes:

```
void testgetPositionByColor() {
        assertEquals(Position.GOALKEEPER, Position.getPositionByColor("BLACK"));
        assertEquals(Position.DEFENDER, Position.getPositionByColor("RED"));
        assertEquals(Position.MIDFIELDER, Position.getPositionByColor("GREEN"));
        assertEquals(Position.FORWARD, Position.getPositionByColor("BLUE"));
        assertNull(Position.getPositionByColor("WHITE"));
        assertNull(Position.getPositionByColor("black"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que los tres metodos que enseñas están en la misma clase, tendrías que hacer el metodo `getPosition` estático, y hacerlo retornar `Strings` , algo así:

```
public static String getPositionByColor (String color) {
        switch (color){
            case "BLACK":
                return Position.GOALKEEPER.toString();
            case "RED":
                return Position.DEFENDER.toString();
            case "GREEN":
                return Position.MIDFIELDER.toString();
            case "BLUE":
                return Position.FORWARD.toString();
            default:
                   return "";
        }
}
```

Y llamarlo correctamente en los test:

```
void testgetPositionByColor() {
    assertEquals(Position.GOALKEEPER, getPositionByColor("BLACK"));
    assertEquals(Position.DEFENDER, getPositionByColor("RED"));
    assertEquals(Position.MIDFIELDER, getPositionByColor("GREEN"));
    assertEquals(Position.FORWARD, getPositionByColor("BLUE"));
    assertNull(getPositionByColor("WHITE"));
    assertNull(getPositionByColor("black"));
}
```

Si no están en la misma clase, yo creo que la solución sería la misma, ya que un `enum` como el que presentas es un patrón común que suele ser estático. La diferencia es que en el test deberías reverenciarlo correctamente con la clase.

Saludos !

Comment: no, los test están en otra clase y no puedo editarlos. Igualmente hago la prueba con la sugerencia que haces ya que veo que ```toString``` era buena opción pero no en la forma en la que lo he hecho yo.